# check if user input is equal to the value of a specific dictionary key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with countries as keys, capitals as values and want to know if there is a way to check if a word when entered as an input, matches the value of **a specific key**?

For example, in the case of `{"England" : "London"}`, when I type "London", is it possible to check if this input is "England"'s value or not? If true, it will print "correct answer".
Thanks.

Comment: It's possible if you iterate through every key in the dictionary and map its value against the word you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Is this is the only application for this dictionary, you should consider having a dictionary that maps capitals to countries instead.  (As a general rule of thumb, the key should be whatever you "know" when you access the dictionary)

To check if a value is in a dictionary, we can do `if v in d.values()`.

If instead you want all the keys that have `value` as their value, we can do something like

```
l = [k for k, v in d.items() if v == value]
```

Then `l` will be a `list` of all the keys that have the value you're looking up

Comment: Most elegant and simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try reversing your dictionary:

```
d = {'England': 'London', 'Spain': 'Madrid', 'France': 'Paris'}

rev_d = {city: country for country, city in d.items()}

def lookup(d, city, country):
    return True if d[city] == country else False

print(lookup(rev_d, 'London', 'England'))
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you want be a nested for loop, like this:

```
for k in dict:
        for v in dict[k]:
            if searchFor in v:
                return k
```